# Contact Form in ASP.NET only refreshing page on POST request

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms, post

I have made a simple contact form in ASP.NET, using a controller, view and viewmodel.

The form is made in Umbraco, so the syntax may look slightly different. I am using the BeginUmbracoForm helper method to make the POST request and call the post action in the controller.

But when i click the submit button, the page is refreshed, no post action is occurring. The mail cannot be sent at this time, as I am running this from a local server, but I would like to have the FormSubmitted message to display, to indicate things are working.

Why is no POST request made?

This is my controller, which inherits from SurfaceController.

```
public class ContactController : SurfaceController
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return PartialView("ContactForm", new ContactFormViewModel());
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Submit(ContactFormViewModel model)
        {

            if (!ModelState.IsValid) //validation
                return CurrentUmbracoPage();

            // Send mail using SMTP
            MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
            mailMessage.To.Add("thomasbrun12@gmail.com");
            mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("info@remaloevbjerg.dk");
            mailMessage.Subject = "Kontakt mail";
            mailMessage.Body = "Navn: " + model.Navn + "\nAddresse: " + model.Addresse + ", " +
                model.PostNrBy + "\nTelefon: " + model.Telefon + "\n" + model.Message;

            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.curanet.dk");
            smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);

            TempData["FormSubmitted"] = true;

            return RedirectToCurrentUmbracoPage();
        }
    }
```

And this is my view:

```
@model LoevbjergRema1000Umbraco.Models.ContactFormViewModel
@using LoevbjergRema1000Umbraco.Controllers;

@{
    Html.EnableClientValidation(true);
    Html.EnableUnobtrusiveJavaScript(true);
}

@if (Convert.ToBoolean(TempData["FormSubmitted"]))
{
    <div>Tak for din henvendelse.</div>
}
else
{
    using (Html.BeginUmbracoForm<ContactController>("Submit"))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <form class="form-inline" id="kontaktForm">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Navn</label>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Navn, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Indtast navn..." })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Navn)
                            <label for="">Addresse</label>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Addresse, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Indtast addresse..." })
                            <label for="">Postnr. + by</label>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PostNrBy, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Indtast postnr & by..." })
                            <label for="">Telefon</label>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Telefon, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Indtast telefonnr..." })
                            <label for="">Email</label>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Indtast email..." })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <label for="">Skriv din besked</label>
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Message, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "kontaktBesked", @rows = "11", @placeholder = "Indtast din besked her..." })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Message)
                    <button class="btn_1 pull-right contact-btn" name="submit" type="submit">Afsend Besked</button>
                    <button class="btn_1 contact-btn">Ryd felter</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you feel that your form is not Posting correctly then there are probably a few things to check,

is your model valid? is there some kind of validation event that is trying to fire and failing, have a look in your console and see if you are getting some kind of error. this maybe causing the browser to refresh rather than submitting the form.

if a `get` is happening rather than a `post`, you can force your form to be a post by specifying `FormMethod.Post` in your form constructor function(`Html.BeginUmbracoForm`), you shouldn't really have to do this, have a look at the html that gets generated, is the form tag being generated correctly (because its umbraco the url it is posting to wont be as straight forward as standard MVC as it is being generated by the `Html.BeginUmbracoForm` method, but it should still make sense)